# How to use single SplashScreenImage.jpg file for multiple Windows Phone resolutions

Tags: windows-phone-8, splash-screen, screen-resolution

In documentation stated that it is enough to keep the only WXGA splashscreen file and it will be scaled by windows Phone OS automatically.

> To display a splash screen for all resolutions, use a single image
>   file named SplashScreenImage.jpg that is 768 × 1280. The phone
>   automatically scales the image to the correct size.
>
> [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Splashscreens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Splashscreens)

But when I'm using the only file no scaling occurs. I still could see black line on the top of the phone during app start.

Sample here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/SplashSample.zip

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: The docs are saying that technically, you can use one splash screen image in a WP8 app, but you should use 3 to support all resolutions - so use 3 images :)

Comment: It says that image will be scaled, doesn't it? I have attached sample

Comment: It's true that it scales you image and it scales it to 720x1200 which is why there is 80px black space above your screen. I don't know whether this is expected behavior or not, but it is weird. You should ask this question in MSDN to get sooner response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll notice that it says "scale" and not stretch - which is exactly what's happening. [Windows Phone 8 supports 3 resolutions](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-8-Multiple-Screen-Resolutions.aspx) (so far)...

1. 480x800 (15:9)
2. 720x1280 (16:9)
3. 768x1280 (15:9)

You'll notice that the aspect ratio of **#1** and **#3** are the same, but **#2** is different - and that's the problem.

For an image to fit all resolutions it would have to be stretched, which would look very bad so Windows Phone 8 doesn't do that. Instead, it scales the image to fit the screen but [a black/white bar appears at the top of screen](http://wmpoweruser.com/in-windows-phone-8-1280x720-is-actually-better-than-1280x768/) for **#2**.

The only way to avoid the black/white bar at the top of the screen is to create 3 separate splash screen and [specify them in the WP8 manifest file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247542%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_pageappui).

**Note:** Making your app work and look correct at multiple resolutions is what every app developer should do. All the major platforms (iOS, Android, Windows 8, etc) support multiple screen sizes and/or resolutions so creating multiple icons sizes, splash screen sizes, background images, and other assets is part of the jobs.

Comment: I have tested on small solution and 3 separate splashes are the only way to avoid having black bar at the top. Moreover you cannot specify splashscreen in Manifest - they should have specific name (MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a "splashscreen.jpg" is a good choice in wp8 any longer, even the templates of sdk doesn't have one.

The reason is if the firts page of your app is massive and your have a splashScreen, you may find your screen blink when starting.

So I would add a blank page and set it as the first page. Also you can add your "Splashscreen" Image here.